# Greendao 3, make users table with no duplicate user names

Tags: android, database, sqlite, greendao, greendao3

I ask this question after searching for hours for the solution to this problem and did not find it.
I have build a database with three columns: username, password and age.
I am able to isert new users and update them, but I want it to be impossible to insert two identical user names. I know how to do it in sqlite but in greendao it just does not go for me. thank you.

here is my UsersClass:

```
@Entity(nameInDb = "users")
public class Users{

    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private int age;
}
```

Comment: *it just does not go for me* - why not, if you know how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I knew how to do it in sqlite.. but not in greendao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Unique` annotation should work for you.

```
@Entity(nameInDb = "users")
public class Users{

    @Id(autoincrement = true)
    private Long id;

    @Unique
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private int age;
}
```

If you need to customize further you can add options to the @Entity annotation

```
@Entity(
    ...
    // Define indexes spanning multiple columns here.
    indexes = {
            @Index(value = "name DESC", unique = true)
    },
    ...
)
```

Comment: It still not working... i did exaclly what you said but it allow me to insert duplicate usernames

Comment: Could you check the table definition on the generated SQLite file? It might give a clue of where the error is.

Comment: @Danielblue, great to hear that, could you [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then please? Also, which of the methods did you use? `@Unique` or adding an `@Index` inside the entity annotation?

Comment: sure! It was @Unique